# SQL: query one column in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

A football manager here. How do I:

1. Select all matches that have kicked-off but never had a goal.
2. Select all matches that kicked-off more than 1h ago but haven't yet had a goal or a corner-kick.

   ```
   | Match | Event       | EventTime           |
   |-------------------------------------------|
   | 1     | Kick-off    | 2014-12-15T16:00:00 |
   | 1     | Throw-in    | 2014-12-15T16:15:00 |
   | 1     | Goal        | 2014-12-15T16:20:00 |
   | 1     | Corner-kick | 2014-12-15T16:30:00 |
   | 1     | End         | 2014-12-15T17:30:00 |
   | 2     | Kick-off    | 2014-12-10T16:00:00 |
   | 2     | Goal        | 2014-12-10T16:01:00 |
   | 3     | Kick-off    | 2014-12-05T08:00:00 |
   | 3     | Corner-kick | 2014-12-05T08:10:00 |
   ```

I feel this should be simple, but I'm stuck somehow.

Comment: What did you try that failed ?

Comment: select Match
    from MyTable
    where Event = 'Kick-off'
    and Event <> 'Goal'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT Match
FROM dbo.YourTable A
WHERE [Event] = 'Kick-off'
AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM dbo.YourTable 
                WHERE Match = A.Match
                AND [Event] = 'Goal')
```

**2:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT Match
FROM dbo.YourTable A
WHERE [Event] = 'Kick-off' 
AND EventTime <= GETDATE(HOUR,-1,GETDATE())
AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM dbo.YourTable 
                WHERE Match = A.Match
                AND [Event] IN ('Goal','Corner-kick'))
```

Comment: I think your first one should also be `NOT EXISTS`

Comment: Thank you very much indeed, Lamak. Your solution has worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

You would do this with aggregation and a `having` clause.  For the first:

```
select match
from table t
group by match
having sum(case when event = 'Kick-off' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when event = 'Goal' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

For the second:

```
select match
from table t
group by match
having max(sum case when event = 'Kick-off' then eventtime end) <= getdate() - 1.0/24 and
       sum(case when event in ('Goal', 'Corner-Kick') then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Each condition in the `having` clause counts the number of rows that match the condition.  `> 0` means that at least one row matched.  `= 0` means no rows match.

Comment: The second one is missing the Corner Kick requirement. Other than that, seems good to me, so +1

Comment: Thank you Gordon. I've preferred Lamak's solution because it avoids 'group by'.

Comment: @MihaiNagy `select distinct` is functionally equivalent to a `group by`.